# Can I group the Memcached keys so that I can flush a group but the total Memcached

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

I use Memcached to store content lists with very key combinations, when user edited the content, I must refresh the cache, but it is hard to say what particular list to refresh, it is not either a good idea to flush the entire Memcached server, so my question is: Can I group the Memcached keys so that I can flush a group but the total Memcached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcached does not have support for range queries so unfortunately you cannot flush a subset of keys.

Answer (score 3):

Memcached does not natively support flushing of the cache group. What you could try is to group your Memcached keys in namespaces. Check the [Memcached wiki](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/ProgrammingTricks#namespacing) for more information.

If by any chance you're using **Spring Boot** you could try the auto-configuration [library](https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot) for the Memcached cache. The library supports clearing out of the cache group.